# Open VB.NET Form inside C# function

Tags: c#, vb.net

I wonder if you can open a `VB.NET` form1 from `C#` form1
like `VB.NET` `Form1.Show();` inside the button function of the `C#` code. I just thought of this will trying learn various code in them, can someone help to verify if this is possible???

Comment: Well you'd create an instance of the form then call `Show` on it, yes.

Comment: It looks like you might be used to using the "default instance" from the VB side.  As far as I know, that's purely a VB construction and would not be available from C#.  On the C# side, you would need something like `var form = new Form1(); form.Show();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Yes, but you can't have C# and VB.net in a single project.  So create a solution containing two projects, one in C# the other in Vb.Net and you can open the vb.Net project form in C# as you suggest.

There is one major consideration though - that's dependencies.  For this to work, the vb.net project is a dependency of the c# project, so the C# project sees all the VB.Net project but not the other way around.

It is possible to configure the solution to make both projects reference eachother - here's a post about it. [Reference in two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202317/reference-in-two-projects/47288278#comment82164816_47288278)

However that's complicated and so I'd suggest having a third project (or fourth if needed) that contains any code you want to have common to both the VB and C# projects as a dependency to them both.

Comment: oh, wow, I'll try to make it, very interesting for me, THANKS ALOT MAN

Comment: Glad it helped.  Could you mark this as the answer, please?